# ssh-agent no longer working

Tags: git, ssh-agent

I used to execute `eval $(ssh-agent -s)` from `git bash`. It would give me a message and all was fine.

Today, it's no longer outputting anything and a `ps -ef | grep ssh` yields no results. It's like ssh-agent either does nothing or fails silently.

I haven't manually installed/updated anything so I have no clue why this has started happening.

I've tried re-installing git to no avail. I've rebooted numerous times.

```
Windows 10
Git 2.36.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on Windows 11. As of I know, Windows's OpenSSH agent does not start on system startup by default. I have never been able to start and monitor it as a Windows service, as suggested by some answers on the issue.

A solution I adopted (as replied [here](https://superuser.com/a/1024921/931886), [full ref.](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/wiki/Auto-launching-ssh-agent-when-git-starts)) is to check the agent state (and start it if needed) every time a Git shell is opened, which can be achieved by adding the following snippet on either one of your Git `bash` [startup files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) (like `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile`):

```
# ssh-agent auto-launch (0 = agent running with key; 1 = w/o key; 2 = not run.)
agent_run_state=$(ssh-add -l >| /dev/null 2>&1; echo $?)
if   [ $agent_run_state = 2 ]; then
  eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
elif [ $agent_run_state = 1 ]; then
  ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
fi
```

The snippet assumes the only key you want to forward is `~/.ssh/id_rsa`, which may not be your case.

Comment: Unfortunately, calling ssh-agent is the issue, it doesnt do anything at all.